# Calculating average by column in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a table with average calculation horizontally using
 JavaScript

**Sample:**

```
Subject | Term1 | Term2 | Term3 | Term4 |   Ave  
   Math      81      87      81      80    82.4 
Science      89      83      81      80    83.25
```

But I've realized that it should be this way...

**Desired table:**

```
Subject | Term1 | Term2 | Term3 | Term4  
   Math      81      87      81      80    
Science      89      83      81      80
Average |    85 |    85 |    81 |    80
```

On the first table, I find it a bit easy to loop over the td tag and
 add its value. But now I don't have any idea how to calculate the
 average column by column. So my problem now is the JavaScript part.

**HTML**

```
     <tr>                 
             <th colspan="3">Learning Areas</th>
             <th colspan="2">Term 1</th>
             <th colspan="2">Term 2</th>
             <th colspan="2">Term 3</th>
             <th colspan="2">Term 4</th>
             <th>Ave</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                  @foreach($card['AllGrade'] as $subject)
                  {!! Form::hidden('grade_id[]',$subject['grade_id']) !!} 




 <tr>
    <td colspan="3">{!! $subject->subject !!}</td> 
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_1[]" value="{!! $subject->term_1 !!}" class="form-control number-only"></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_2[]" value="{!! $subject->term_2 !!}" class="form-control number-only"></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_3[]" value="{!! $subject->term_3 !!}" class="form-control number-only"></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_4[]" value="{!! $subject->term_4 !!}" class="form-control number-only"></td>
    </tr>

   @endforeach





<tr>
                <td colspan="2">Average Grade :</td>
                <td id="t1" value="">term1</td>
                <td id="t2" value="">term2</td>
                <td id="t3" value=">term3</td>
                <td id="t4" value=">term4</td>
        </tr>
```

**Complete view.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout.Master')

@section('content')
@include('errors.input_error')  
{!!Html::style('assets/css/tag/bootstrap-tagsinput.css')!!}
{!!Html::style('assets/css/tag/app.css')!!}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
@if($update_card->scholar_grade_level == 'Graduated_Secondary')
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2"> 
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Update Card Information</h3></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'Update-Card-Information/'.$update_card->scholar_card_id,'files'=>true)) !!}
                        {!! Form::hidden('scholar_id',$update_card->scholar_id) !!}
                        {!! Form::hidden('scholar_grade_level',$update_card->scholar_grade_level) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Name of School :</label>
                                <select name="school_id" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select School</option>
                                    @foreach($location_name as $schools)
                                    <optgroup label="{!! $schools->location_name !!}">
                                        @foreach($schools['schoollocation'] as $scho)
                                        <option value="{!! $scho->school_id !!}"@if($update_card->school_id == $scho->school_id)selected="selected" @endif>{!! $scho->school_name !!}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </optgroup>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">School year :</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="scholar_school_year">
                                        <?php 
                                        $null = 'null';
                                        $choose = 'Choose A Year';
                                        $Present = 'Present';
                                        echo '<option value='.$null.'>' .$choose.'</option>';
                                        if ($update_card->scholar_school_year ==  'Present' ) {
                                            echo '<option value="Present" selected="selected">' .$Present.'</option>';
                                        }else{
                                            echo '<option value="Present">' .$Present.'</option>';
                                        }
                                        for($i=date('Y');  $i > date('Y')-30; $i--){

                                            $x = $i +1;
                                            $y = $i;
                                            $pass = $y.'-'.$x;
                                            if ($update_card->scholar_school_year ==  $pass ) {
                                                echo '<option value='.$y.'-'.$x.' selected="selected">'.$y.'-'.$x.'</option>';
                                            }else{
                                                echo '<option value='.$y.'-'.$x.'>'.$y.'-'.$x.'</option>';
                                            }
                                        }?>
                                    </select>                                           
                                </div>  
                                <div class=" form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Awards and Recognation:</label>
                                    {!! Form::text('scholar_awards',$update_card->scholar_awards,['class'=>'form-control','data-role'=>'tagsinput'])!!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    {!!Form::submit('Update Card',['class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {!! Form::close() !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
@if($update_card->scholar_grade_level >= 7 && $update_card->scholar_grade_level <= 10 && $update_card->scholar_school_year == 'Present' && $update_card->scholar_grade_level != 'Graduated_Primary' && $update_card->scholar_grade_level != 'Graduated_Secondary' && $update_card->scholar_grade_level != 'Graduated_Senior')
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2"> 
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Update Card Information</h3></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'Update-Card-Information/'.$update_card->scholar_card_id,'files'=>true)) !!}
                        {!! Form::hidden('scholar_id',$update_card->scholar_id) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Name of School :</label>
                                <select name="school_id" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select School</option>
                                    @foreach($location_name as $schools)
                                    <optgroup label="{!! $schools->location_name !!}">
                                        @foreach($schools['schoollocation'] as $scho)
                                        <option value="{!! $scho->school_id !!}"@if($update_card->school_id == $scho->school_id)selected="selected" @endif>{!! $scho->school_name !!}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </optgroup>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">School year :</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="scholar_school_year">
                                        <?php 
                                        $null = 'null';
                                        $choose = 'Choose A Year';
                                        $Present = 'Present';
                                        echo '<option value='.$null.'>' .$choose.'</option>';
                                        if ($update_card->scholar_school_year ==  'Present' ) {
                                            echo '<option value="Present" selected="selected">' .$Present.'</option>';
                                        }else{
                                            echo '<option value="Present">' .$Present.'</option>';
                                        }
                                        for($i=date('Y');  $i > date('Y')-30; $i--){

                                            $x = $i +1;
                                            $y = $i;
                                            $pass = $y.'-'.$x;
                                            if ($update_card->scholar_school_year ==  $pass ) {
                                                echo '<option value='.$y.'-'.$x.' selected="selected">'.$y.'-'.$x.'</option>';
                                            }else{
                                                echo '<option value='.$y.'-'.$x.'>'.$y.'-'.$x.'</option>';
                                            }
                                        }?>
                                    </select>                                           
                                </div>                                  
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Grade Level : </label>
                                {!! Form::select('scholar_grade_level', [
                                ''=>'Choose a Year Level',
                                '7' => 'Grade-7',
                                '8' => 'Grade-8',
                                '9' => 'Grade-9',
                                '10' => 'Grade-10'
                                ],$update_card->scholar_grade_level,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Average grade : </label>
                                {!! Form::text('scholar_GPA',$update_card->scholar_GPA,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                            </div>  
                            @if($update_card->scholar_grade_level == 10)
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Choose Track(For Senior High) : </label>  
                                {!! Form::select('senior_track_id', ['' => 'Choose A Senior High Track'] + $seniors, $update_card->scholar_track , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                            </div>
                            @endif  
                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Awards and Recognation:</label>
                                {!! Form::text('scholar_awards',$update_card->scholar_awards,['class'=>'form-control','data-role'=>'tagsinput'])!!}
                            </div>      
                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Upload Card(Proof Grade) :</label>
                                @foreach($update_card['CardProof'] as $subject1)
                                {!! Form::hidden('card_proof_id',$subject1->card_proof_id) !!} 
                                {!! Form::file('card_proof_5') !!}
                                @endforeach
                            </div>                                    
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                {!!Form::submit('Update Card',['class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block']) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
@if($update_card->scholar_grade_level >= 7 && $update_card->scholar_grade_level <= 10 && $update_card->scholar_school_year != 'Present' && $update_card->scholar_grade_level != 'Graduated_Primary' && $update_card->scholar_grade_level != 'Graduated_Secondary' && $update_card->scholar_grade_level != 'Graduated_Senior')
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12"> 
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Update Card Information</h3></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'Update-Card-Information/'.$update_card->scholar_card_id,'files'=>true)) !!}
                        {!! Form::hidden('scholar_id',$update_card->scholar_id) !!}
```

**Beginning of the table for this specific form**

```
   <div class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="6">
                                            <h3>School Name : 
                                                <select name="school_id" class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="">Select School</option>
                                                    @foreach($location_name as $schools)
                                                    <optgroup label="{!! $schools->location_name !!}">
                                                        @foreach($schools['schoollocation'] as $scho)
                                                        <option value="{!! $scho->school_id !!}"@if($update_card->school_id == $scho->school_id)selected="selected" @endif>{!! $scho->school_name !!}</option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </optgroup>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                            </h3>
                                        </th>
                                        <th colspan="3">
                                            <h3>Grade Level : 
                                                {!! Form::select('scholar_grade_level', [
                                                ''=>'Choose a Year Level',
                                                '7' => 'Grade-7',
                                                '8' => 'Grade-8',
                                                '9' => 'Grade-9',
                                                '10' => 'Grade-10'
                                                ],$update_card->scholar_grade_level,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                                            </h3>
                                        </th>
                                        <th colspan="3">
                                            <h3>School Year : 
                                                <select class="form-control" name="scholar_school_year">
                                                    <?php 
                                                    $null = 'null';
                                                    $choose = 'Choose A Year';
                                                    $Present = 'Present';
                                                    echo '<option value='.$null.'>' .$choose.'</option>';
                                                    if ($update_card->scholar_school_year ==  'Present' ) {
                                                        echo '<option value="Present" selected="selected">' .$Present.'</option>';
                                                    }else{
                                                        echo '<option value="Present">' .$Present.'</option>';
                                                    }
                                                    for($i=date('Y');  $i > date('Y')-30; $i--){

                                                        $x = $i +1;
                                                        $y = $i;
                                                        $pass = $y.'-'.$x;
                                                        if ($update_card->scholar_school_year ==  $pass ) {
                                                            echo '<option value='.$y.'-'.$x.' selected="selected">'.$y.'-'.$x.'</option>';
                                                        }else{
                                                            echo '<option value='.$y.'-'.$x.'>'.$y.'-'.$x.'</option>';
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>                                           
                                            </h3>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="12"><h4>SCHOLASTIC ACHIEVEMENT</h4></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="3">Subjects</th>
                                        <th colspan="2">First Grading</th>
                                        <th colspan="2">Second Grading</th>
                                        <th colspan="2">Third Grading</th>
                                        <th colspan="2">Fourth Grading</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>   
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach($update_card['AllGrade'] as $subject)
                                    {!! Form::hidden('grade_id[]',$subject['grade_id']) !!} 
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3">{!! $subject->subject !!}</td> 
                                        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_1[]" value="{!! $subject->term_1 !!}" class="form-control number-only"></td>
                                        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_2[]" value="{!! $subject->term_2 !!}" class="form-control number-only"></td>
                                        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_3[]" value="{!! $subject->term_3 !!}" class="form-control number-only"></td>
                                        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_4[]" value="{!! $subject->term_4 !!}" class="form-control number-only"></td>

                                    </tr>

                                    @endforeach
                                     <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">0</td> <td colspan="2">0</td> <td colspan="2">0</td> <td colspan="2">0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="3">Upload Card(Proof Grade) :</th>
                                        @foreach($update_card['CardProof'] as $subject1)
                                        {!! Form::hidden('card_proof_id',$subject1->card_proof_id) !!} 
                                        <th colspan="2">
                                            {!! Form::file('card_proof_1') !!}
                                        </th> 
                                        <th colspan="2">
                                            {!! Form::file('card_proof_2') !!}
                                        </th> 
                                        <th colspan="2">
                                            {!! Form::file('card_proof_3') !!}
                                        </th> 
                                        <th colspan="2">
                                            {!! Form::file('card_proof_4') !!}
                                        </th> 
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Awards and Recognation:</label>
                            {!! Form::text('scholar_awards',$update_card->scholar_awards,['class'=>'form-control','data-role'=>'tagsinput'])!!}
                        </div>
                        @if($update_card->scholar_grade_level == 10)
                        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Choose Track(For Senior High) : </label>  
                            {!! Form::select('senior_track_id', ['' => 'Choose A Senior High Track'] + $seniors, $update_card->scholar_track , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                        </div>
                        @endif  
                        <div class="col-lg-12"></div>                                      
                        <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
                            {!!Form::submit('Update Card',['class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block']) !!}
                        </div>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

**Script**

```
$("input").on("keyup", function() {

      $("tbody tr").each(function() {

      $(this).children('td').not(':first').each(function() {



      });

});
```

Comment: Your question should include your own personal attempts, rather than just asking for the code to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: you can use SumTerm1, SumTerm2....so on and CountTerm1, CountTerm2....so on within your loop. get avg at the end(outside loop)

Comment: @techLove - Thanks for the idea sir.Actually I am working on it since yesterday while doing research at the same time then apply to my code but still dont get it.That is why I'm here in stack hoping to get something.

Comment: You target `tr td:nth-child(x)` etc, sum them up and divide on the number of TD's *(tip : length)* !

Comment: @adeneo - Sir let me clarify, divide by number of TD? or number of ROWs?It should be divided by number of subjects or number of rows

Comment: It's basic math, if you have the numbers `81` and `89`, what you do to get the average is add them up to a total of `170`, and since there are two numbers, you divide by two and get `(81 + 89) / 2 === 85`

Comment: @adeneo - I knew the calculation part but in targeting all the TDs of the same columns and get each  column average  is what i don't know sir.

Comment: Are the tables dynamically created from some data? If so, you should calculate the average using the underlying data, not by parsing the HTML output which was constructed from the data.

Comment: @Santi - Sir i have my scripts for the calculation by rows but since I made up my mind in getting the average by column instead of by rows.I have already added a script as what you had requested but this is only what i had started because i am confuse on targetting the TDs of each column so I can add and get the average.It might be easy for me if it has one column but this one has four columns.

Comment: You can supply a parameter in your `each()` function that refers to the index of the current iteration, like this: `.each(function(x) { ... } )`. You can then do something like `$("tr").last().children().eq(x)` to get the corresponding cell.

Comment: @DanielWaltrip - Yes sir, the data is from my database but this HTML form is for update.The reason i put a keyup is because every changes that the user do should update dynamically on its average before updating/submitting the form to save in the database.

Comment: @Santi - I will try to experiment arround these syntax sir.Thank you.

Comment: @Chiloy Made a quick example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y0hgpp8w/1/).

Comment: @Santi - Sir I saw the fiddle  and it is my first time to see the way you do it that is why it is hard for me to formulate a logic because of my little knowledge.I will give it a try and tell you then the results.

Comment: @Santi - I having a  hard time implementing your code because my table is completely different Sir.See my updated post.Its a complete view of blade.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, tell me if you have any questions:

```
    $("input").on("keyup", function() {
         $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
              var sum = 0; // The summation of all terms.
              var card = 0; // Number of cells.
              $(this).children('td').not(':first').each(function(i, e) {
                  card++;
                  sum+= parseInt(e.text().trim());
              });
              var avg = sum/card;
              $("#average td:nth-of-type("+index+")").html(avg);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can I update my blade.php Sir? My view that I'd posted is just part of a whole.I will post the complete one right after the first one just to show the how complex the view is.This might be helpful to give an overview of the whole page because i might get lost in interpreting your code.And much better that everyone can see how my table looks like.

Comment: I will try this code sir and see i could  do something on it..By the way what is the parameter " i " for?

Comment: I'd tried to alert and the results are NaN for 12 times.Why?

Comment: Oh sorry, text is a function in jQuery not an attribute. I updated my answer try again please.

Comment: Sir, I made some update on the last tr. The resulting values in each TDs are zeroes.Meaning the result of the calculation are not in the right target?

Comment: Oh sorry I hadn't update my answer. I also added a trim function to remove any undesirable spaces before and after the number string.

Comment: Your update is the trim only.How about the result of the average?The values are 0,0,0,0 in all TDs.

Comment: I tried to console.log(avg);  It generates error in this line e.text() . It say Uncaught TypeError: e.text is not a function

Comment: Something wrong with this line sir especially the e.text(). sum+= parseInt(e.text().trim());

Comment: I'd tried to debug and it is not calculating the values per column.It should be all the  values of Term1  divided by number of rows or subject.Same us Term2, Term3...Then at the last of the row, it dispays the average  each of the column.